# Twitter4j TwitterStream filter() not working to update parameters

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have a `TwitterStream` object:

```
static TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
```

which I add a listener to, and some user ids to track (the user ids are correct, and this part works):

```
twitterStream.addListener(listener);
twitterStream.filter(new FilterQuery(followArray));
```

The problem, is that inside the listener, in `onStatus(Status status)` I want to add a user to track.  I've tried this two ways, first by simply doing

```
twitterStream.filter(new FilterQuery(newArray));
```

where this `newArray` is the old one plus the new user id, and I've also tried calling

```
twitterStream.cleanUp();
```

before `filter()`.  In both cases, the code appears to run, but then when I tweet from one of the followed accounts, I get the message

> [Tue May 13 15:30:08 EDT 2014]Establishing connection.

and then the program terminates.

I can provide my full code if necessary, but any debugging help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by moving twitterStream.filter() to the onCleanup() method of a ConnectionLifeCycleListener.  This restarts the TwitterStream thread with the new filter after the old one has been cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to sleep the main thread for a period of time. Check whether you have the following code:

```
Thread.sleep(400000)
```

after

```
twitterStream.filter(new FilterQuery(newArray));
```

and before

```
twitterStream.cleanUp
```